# Stop and reset video when carousal swiped - Xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my xamarin.forms app I have a carousal view which have `MediaElement` as template. The videos are played from URL. What I am trying to achieve is when user swipe the carousal items, I want the currently playing video needs to stop and play the next video binded to that cell and when we swipe back, the previous video needs to restart. Currently the playing video will not get closed and when we swipe the next video will also get played along with it.

How can I solve this? Any help is appreciated.

**Carousal View with video.**

```
<CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding }" >    
        <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>    
            <DataTemplate>                       
                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"        >    
    
                 <MediaElement AutoPlay="True" Aspect="AspectFill"
                  Source="{Binding Video}" /  
                </StackLayout>    
            </DataTemplate>    
        </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>    
    </CarouselView>
```

Comment: You can use the position change command|events on `MediaElement` to manually call the `Stop` method on `PreviousItem` parameter. (FYI: We had lots of memory/caching issues w/ `MediaElement` so we use a bound singleton of `MediaElement` and/or a small cache of `MediaElement` controls and bind/pre-cache that LIFO cache list to the template instead of using Xamarin's logic)

Comment: @SushiHangover Hi, Thanks for the response. How can I stop the mediaelement when we use the position changed event? How to call the stop method since the mediaelement is inside carousal? and also thanks for the memmory caching issue info.

Comment: You can bind a position change command in the `CarouselView `'s XAML via `RelativeBindingSourceMode` to its Template's MediaView and one of the command parameters is the `PreviousItem`, which will have a MediaView child and that is the one you call `Stop` on. Relative Bindings: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use BindingContextChanged and PositionChanged Events.

```
<CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding }" PositionChanged="carouselView_PositionChanged">    
        <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>    
            <DataTemplate>                       
                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"        >    
    
                 <MediaElement AutoPlay="True" Aspect="AspectFill"
                  Source="{Binding Video}" BindingContextChanged="MediaElement_BindingContextChanged" />  
                </StackLayout>    
            </DataTemplate>    
        </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>    
    </CarouselView>
```

In Code Behind

```
List<MediaElement> mediaElements = new List<MediaElement>();

private void MediaElement_BindingContextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var element = sender as MediaElement;
            mediaElements.Add(element);
        }

        private void carouselView_PositionChanged(object sender, PositionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            mediaElements[e.PreviousPosition].Stop();
        }
```